# CMD recognizes 'py', but PowerShell doesn't

Tags: python, powershell

Python does not work in PowerShell anymore.

I've never had any problems, until recently. CMD still recognizes the `py` command, but powershell doesn't recognize any of the basic python commands: `py`,`py3`,`python`,`python3`.
My problem occured after I installed MinGW and added its path to the Path variable.

I have restarted my computer many times, while trying new things.

Things I've tried:

- I have tried removing MinGW from the Path variable.
- I have tried uninstalling MinGW.
- I have tried reinstalling python.
- I have tried manually adding the Python path.
- I have tried letting Python automatically add my Python path.
- I have tried adding the Python path to both the user environment variables and the system variables.
- I have tried running PowerShell as administrator.

Finally, this is what my Path variable looks like now:

**User Path Variable:**

```
C:\Users\lcdew\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
C:\Users\lcdew\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin
```

**System Path Variable:**

```
C:\Program Files\Python38\Scripts
C:\Program Files\Python38
C:\Program Files\Scripts
C:\Program Files
C:\Program Files (x86)\Scripts
C:\Program Files (x86)
C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer Chroma SDK\bin
C:\Program Files\Razer Chroma SDK\bin
C:\Windows\system32
C:\Windows
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common
```

Comment: `C:\Program Files` respectively `%ProgramFiles%` and `C:\Program Files (x86)` respectively `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` should be removed from __system__ environment variable `Path` as those two directories contain usually only subdirectories and not files with a file extension as defined in value of __system__ environment variable `PATHEXT`.

Comment: The first five directory paths in __system__ environment variable `Path` should be `%SystemRoot%\System32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;%SystemRoot%\System32\OpenSSH;%SystemRoot%\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps` So I strongly recommend to move the six program files directory paths down (Windows 10) respectively to left (former Windows versions) below/after the `WindowsApps` directory path.

Comment: Restart Windows after making these modifications on __system__ environment variable `Path` to get the update applied to all processes started automatically by Windows after Windows restart. Please take also a look on [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564)

Comment: @Mofi I have tried your suggestion. This is my system Path variable: ```%SystemRoot%\System32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;%SystemRoot%\System32\OpenSSH;%SystemRoot%\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Program Files\Python38\;C:\Program Files\Scripts\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Scripts\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;```

Comment: But it doesn't seem to work. I restarted my computer, but PowerShell still does not recognize ```py```.

Comment: Just happened to me overnight. Just yesterday I was testing .bat files without any issue. Today Powershell(and Powershell7) started requiring the ```.exe``` extension for no apparent reason. Entering "py" alone pops up a "Open with..." window.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem. Apparently I accidentally deleted the `PathExt` variable, which contains the file extensions that the Windows command processor will look for.
So after adding the following variable to the system path variables everything worked:

```
PathExt

.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
```

However, I still don't understand why CMD worked and PowerShell didn't, maybe someone knows the answer to this.

Comment: The Windows command processor `cmd.exe` has included in its code the file extensions list `.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.JS;.WS;.MSC` which is used on environment variable `PATHEXT` not defined at all with more extensions by default. `cmd.exe` is the only executable on Windows with a default path extension list embedded in code for the error condition that the environment variable `PATHEXT` is not defined at all.

Comment: The library file `wshext.dll` contains the file extensions list `.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH` for the error condition that the environment variable `PATHEXT` is not defined at all. For that reason the Windows Script Host (`cscript.exe` (console version) or `wscript.exe` (Windows GUI version)) is the second program which can find executables and scripts specified with just file name without file extension on environment variable `PATHEXT` not defined in local execution environment. All other applications including Windows PowerShell depend on `PATHEXT`.

Answer (score 0):

multiple definitions for app alias may cause it in PowerShell, error is as below:

```
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).